# Difference between abstract class with all method abstract and interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

I had an interview where interviewer asked me first what is the difference between abstract class with all the methods abstract and an interface.

I replied that if it is required to inherit something in the future you will not be able to do it if you have already extended a class.

Then, he stated that it was a situation where one would never have to extend any other class and you have to implement a contract. In this circumstance, which would be better, an abstract class or an interface?

I told him you can use either of them but he was not satisfied. I could not understand why - I believe that is a developer/design choice.

Comment: You can implement many interfaces

Comment: An abstract class can have a constructor, while an interface cannot. However, you'd have to implement that constructor, so I'm not sure if you can call the constructor itself abstract...

Comment: @leo I know but if i do not need to do any other modifications in that class which implements or extends any other functionality then what should i choose? Interface or abstract class and why?

Comment: Just an info , In Java 8 ,You can add default methods and its implementation in interface . IMHO implement interface for the contracts ( hand shake) .

Comment: I think the interviewer was trying to see that if you understood the usage of term "interface".

Comment: Usually when an interviewer asks this kind of question, they have a specific thing in mind -- basically, a keyword they're looking for you you to mention. That's probably why when you said one thing (the multiple inheritance), the interviewer said you should disregard it (in other words "that's a correct answer, but not the one I want"). So, it's really hard to answer this question without knowing what the interviewer was thinking. It sounds like a bad question on the interviewer's part.

Comment: @yshavit I agree. He should contact the interviewer. Or at least, not leave the interview without doubts. I usually ask when i'm on such a situation, it can be useful for the next interview.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer stating that an interface represents a contract is not acceptable.
That's the answer we give to Junior since it may be too complex to clearly figure out the difference between the essence of an abstract class and the essence of an interface without much architecture experience and without reading a lot of classic books about.
Any abstract class with `public` methods acts as a contract, as well as an interface.

An abstract class that doesn't provide any implementation is in 99% of cases a representation of an object's **Role**.
An **interface** represents a **Role**.
Each object might have several different roles that shouldn't be tied together but composed by the concerned object.

**I'm explaining this with this example**:

Your interviewer could say:
I have a `Robot` that can walk and a `Human` that can walk too.

So based on this case, he asks you: should I extract the walking feature in an abstract base class or in an interface, knowing that the implementations have nothing in common?

You think..."oh I know so: in this case, having one abstract class with an abstract method `walk()`, then is clearly the same than declaring an interface with the `walk()` method."
So your answer would surely be: "it's the choice of the developer !".
And it's really not an always valid answer.

Why? Let's see the next expectation:
A `Human` can eat, but obviously the `Robot` cannot and even doesn't need.

What if you implemented the walking feature with an abstract class? You would end up with:

```
public abstract class Biped {  
  public void abstract walk();
} 

public Robot extends Biped {
   public void walk() {
     //walk at 10km/h speed
   }
}

public Human extends Biped {
   public void walk() {
     //walk at 5km/h speed
   }
}
```

How could you plug the `eating` feature? You're stuck because you can't implement it in the `Biped` base class since it would break **Liskov Substitution Principle**, since a `Robot` doesn't eat!
And you can't expect `Human` extending another base class due to the known Java rule.

Of course, you could add a specific Feedable interface only dedicated to Human:

```
public interface Feedable {
  void eat();
}
```

Signature becomes: `public Human extends Biped implements Feedable {`
Clearly, it makes no sense and confusing to have one **role** implemented through a class and the other through an interface.

That's why starting with interface is really preferred whenever we have the choice.

With an interface, we can model **Roles** easily by composing.

So the final solution would then be:

```
public interface Walkable {
   void abstract walk();
} 

public interface Feedable {
   void eat();
} 

public Robot implements Walkable {
   public void walk() {
     //walk at 10km/h speed
   }
}

public Human implements Walkable, Feedable {
   public void walk() {
     //walk at 5km/h speed
   }

   public void eat(){
     //...
   }    
}
```

Doesn't it remind you the **Interface Segregation Principle**? ;)

To sum up, if you specify an **IS-A** relationship, uses an abstract class.
If you realize that you are about to model a **Role** (let's say a **IS-CAPABLE-OF** relationship), go with interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the differences:

1. A class can extend exactly abstract class, but can implement any number of interfaces.
2. An abstract class can have protected, private (does not apply to your question), package, and public methods, but an interface can only have public methods.
3. An abstract class can have instance variables (often called data members or properties) while an interface can only have static variables.

The answer to the question: "blah never extend blah implement contract blah" is this: "I would use an abstract class if I did needed instance variables and/or non-public methods and otherwise I would use an interface".

Comment: I agree but what about Interface segregation principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle which is in disregard of interviewer?

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are the natural way of creating a contract because they **force** you to implement the methods they define.

Besides that, you can implement as many as you want in the case you want to add new interfaces to your class.

Comment: But the first part (forcing you to implement the methods) is also true of abstract methods, and the second part is a case the interviewer explicitly said the OP should disregard.

Comment: lets assume you do not need any other implementations in future then what are you going to choose interface or abstract class?

Comment: @yshavit True :). Maybe the interviewer had in mind the accessibility, in an interface all methods must be **public**. That's more like a contract. But.. abstract methods can also be declared as public :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what your interviewer had in mind, but an interface is more of a "contract" whereas an abstract base class, while it can play that role too, is more geared towards hierarchies or IS-A relationships. E.g. an Apple IS-A Fruit, a Pear IS-A Fruit, etc. But you're right, they could well be used interchangeably for practical purposes in that context, but an OO purist might not want to use an abstract class unless they were expressing IS-A relationship(s).

Comment: Ahh thats not it lets take an example a class which extends Thread is a thread and a class which implements Runnable  force a direct implementation...its on developer what is his choice ...right...but if Thread was an abstract class with only run method as abstract then what would you have choosen?

Comment: There's a minor distinction between implementing Runnable and extending Thread. Implementing Runnable, you use a Thread to run it, e.g. composition. Extending Thread you are using is-a to extend/customize a Thread's behavior (if needed). I would implement Runnable. Here's another thread (pardon the pun) on it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread].

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is be the ability to have diamond inheritance for interfaces.

Consider this interface hierarchy:

```
interface Base{}

interface Sub1 extends Base{}

interface Sub2 extends Base{}

interface SubSub extends Sub1, Sub2{}
```

The same wouldn't be possible with abstract classes:

```
abstract class Base{}

abstract class Sub1 extends Base{}

abstract class Sub2 extends Base{}

// NOT ALLOWED! can only extend one class
// abstract class SubSub extends Sub1, Sub2{}
```

This is something that would be allowed in C++ (although tricky to get right). I think he might have been fishing for this. In general, this is the ultimate reason why I always try to write interface hierarchies instead of class hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

For the first situation i'd chose interface over abstract class with all methods abstract as having interface leaves me with option in future for my implementing class to extend some other (abstract) class.

For second scenario, if you really don't want your concrete class to extend any other class and also want to "implement" contract, you can have abstract class with all methods abstract.

Comment: And what should i choose?

Comment: I think the question you were asked was more of a discussion starter than one word answer -interface or abstract class. You should have answered like what you would use in which scenario.

Comment: A question must have a right answer thats what i think untill and unless its a NP-hard problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard

Comment: If it was not interview than I'd agree with you. each question in interview is not always about right or wrong answer but it's about knowing candidate's analytical skill s, presence of mind, problem approaching and solving attitude. I might be wrong here as i know little about you interview. So only best person to get the answer is the interviewer. IMHO for such open ended questions there is no one perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see such question was already answered. BTW, I would like to share what I consider the best explanation I have read so far.

The bellow text was copied and pasted from Deshmukh, Hanumant. OCP Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 11 Programmer I Exam Fundamentals 1Z0-815: Study guide for passing the OCP Java 11 Developer Certification Part 1 Exam 1Z0-815 (p. 319). Enthuware. Edição do Kindle.

13.2 Distinguish class inheritance from interface inheritance including abstract classes 13.2.1 Difference between Interface and Abstract Class ☝

"What is the difference between an interface and an abstract class" is usually the first question that is asked in a Java "tech-check". While being a simple ice breaker, it also an excellent question to judge a candidate's understanding of OOP. Candidates usually start parroting the technical differences such as an interface cannot have method implementations (which it can, since Java 8), while abstract class can. An interface cannot have static methods (which it can, since Java 8) or instance fields while an abstract class can and so on. All that is correct, but is not really impressive. The fundamental difference between an interface and an abstract class is that an interface defines just the behavior. An interface tells you nothing about the actual object other than how it behaves. An abstract class, on the other hand, defines an object, which in turn, drives the behavior. If you understand this concept everything else about them will fall in place. For example, "movement" is a behavior that is displayed by various kinds of objects such as a Car, a Cat, or a StockPrice. These objects have no commonality except that they move. Saying it the other way round, if you get an object that "moves", you don't get any idea about what kind of an object are you going to deal with. It could be a Car, a Cat, or a StockPrice. If you were to capture this behavior in Java, you would use an interface named Movable with a method named move(). On the other hand, if you talk about Automobile, a picture of an object starts forming in your head immediately. You can sense that an Automobile would be something that would have an engine, would have wheels, and would move. You intuitively know that a StockPrice or a Cat cannot be an Automobile even though they both do move. An abstract class is meant exactly for this purpose, when, once you identify a conceptual object, you do not need to worry about its behavior. The behavior kind of flows automatically. If you create an abstract class named Automobile, you are almost certain that it would have methods such a move, turn, accelerate, or brake. It would have fields for capturing inner details such Engine, Wheels, and Gears. You get all that just by saying the word Automobile. From the above discussion, it should be clear that interfaces and abstract classes are not interchangeable. Even though an abstract class with no non-abstract method looks functionally similar to an interface, both are fundamentally different. If you are capturing a behavior, you must use an interface. If you are capturing a conceptual object, you must use an abstract class.